# Como colocar imagem no background do Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css3

Estou criando um template no wordpress, só que agora não estou conseguindo colocar uma imagem de background no fundo do site :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui inserir a cor dando um id="bg" pro body, pois quando tentei apenas pegar o elemento body, o css do wordpress reescrevia o meu e então não era possível alterar a cor.

```
#bg {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

só que quando tento colocar uma imagem como background nada acontece(o diretório está correto.).

```
#bg {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    background-image: url('/assets/images/bg/orange.png');
}
```

Comment: background-image: url('/assets/images/bg/orange.png') !important; faz o teste...

Comment: já tentei com !important tb e sem sucesso :/

Comment: coloca o estilo direto na tag html, se funcionar o path está certo e tem algum estilo se sobrepondo se não funcionar o path está errado....ex: <div id="bg" style="background:url('/assets/images/bg/orange.png')no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;"></div>

Comment: o caminho pra imagem está correto?

Comment: Amigo, de uma olhada na aba netwrok do console dev do browser para ver a ordem de carregamento dos arquivos css.

Comment: Olá! Você pode enviar um link com o código ou copiar o código aqui? Assim ficar mais fácil de ajudar. Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses links baseados na raiz podem ser um pouco complicados no wordpress... mas vou tentar explicar:

vc tem o diretório base do WP:

```
wp-content
wp-includes
wp-admin
*vários arquivos
```

agora olhe pra url de cada página do wordpress do seu site:

```
home = www.meusite.com.br/
página1 = www.meusite.com.br/pagina1/
sub página = www.meusite.com.br/página1/subpágina/
```

se vc se basea na home do seu site... uma opção é:
no diretório base do wordpress, criar uma pasta `img`, colocar a imagem ali.

Ai no CSS da home ou da página1 vc acrescenta:

```
#bg {
background-image: url('./img/imagem-de-fundo.png');
}
```

Porém, a partir de outras páginas, como a sub-página, vc precisa de:

```
#bg {
background-image: url('../img/imagem-de-fundo.png');
}
```

repare o `../`, o que quer dizer "no diretório pai do qual me encontro", enquanto `./` diz "no diretório em que me encontro".

uma dica para agilizar e botar tudo num só arquivo de CSS:

veja o id de toda página que não seja uma sub-página:
home = 1, página1 = 2, páginaA = 3.....

e acrescente isso:

```
#bg {
background-image: url('../img/imagem-de-fundo.png');
}
body.page-id-1 #bg, body.page-id-2 #bg, body.page-id-3 #bg {
background-image: url('./img/imagem-de-fundo.png');
}
```

para cada id de página base, vc adiciona um `body.page-id-x #bg`, assim ele vai encontrar o caminho correto pras imagens :)

claro q é uma espécie de gambiarra, outra forma talvez seria com algum plugin mais inteligente.

Mas seu o seu site se basea em meia duzia de páginas principais e até uma tonelada de sub-páginas, vc não deveria ter problemas seguindo esse método.

EDIT:
algumas propriedades que podem te ajudar a fazer o setup da sua imagem de fundo:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp